# Spring annotation configuration java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

i am trying to run a very simple Spring application with java configuration. i am getting the following exception and i dont understand why. as far as i can tell i have all the required dependencies

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) 
> {
>      System.out.println( "Hello World from main!" );
>      ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
>      HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
>      System.out.println( helloWorld.getMessage() );
> }
> ```

The exception occures at - AnnotationConfigApplicationContext function call

worth mentioning:
I have the following dependency in my POM.XML file.

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

And the exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: spring.play.springStart.AppConfig
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:313)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:197)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
> at spring.play.springStart.App.main(App.java:14)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
> at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.toByteArray(DebuggingClassWriter.java:73)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:26)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
> at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
> at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:136)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:303)
> ... 6 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
> ... 17 more
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't really know what solved the problem, but I did go to some tutorial website that does the same thing and just copied their pom file dependencies. 
I still don't understand what was missing.

In any case Balint Bako might be right with his answer but i am not sure, i got it solved by the time I got back to StackOverflow.

Here is the pom file

> ```
>   <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>         <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>         <version>${spring.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- JavaConfig need this library -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>cglib</groupId>
>         <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2.2</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Good luck

Comment: Well, check which jar has the missing class (the spring-core will) and grant the solution mark to my answer ;)

Comment: I had problem with Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE and cglib-3.0, **when changed to cglib-2.2.2 everything worked flawlessly**.

Answer (score 1):

As per exception it seems that ASM related jar is missing. You can add asm-all

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>asm</groupId>
   <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this causes duplicated jars and collides with other dependencies so it wont work\

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me with following dependencies. Thanks Rubens Mariuzzo. You cracked with cglib version problem. It **never worked** with *3.0* but worked with ***2.2.2***

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need spring-core too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when using Spock unit test framework, and using Spy test.
I overcome this issue by add this into my Maven dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```